# Как програмно получить количество ссылок на файл используемый процессами?

Tags: файлы, c, linux

Доброго времени суток всем.
У меня такой вопрос:

Как программно получить количество ссылок на файл (по дескриатору файла), используемый в системе Linux? Существуют ли функции API решающие данную задачу. Если нет, то может быть кто-то уже реализовывал нечто подобное собственными силами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество жестких ссылок можно получить через сисвызов `stat` (через дескриптор файла - `fstat`). У `struct stat` есть поле `st_nlink`. А количество мягких ссылок, боюсь, никак. Единственное, что могу себе представить, это обход всей файловой системы и анализ встреченных мягких ссылок.

Comment: [Жесткая ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%91%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)
[Символьная (мягкая) ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @eigenein, это Вы к чему?

Comment: @mikillskegg, здесь был комментарий ТС с вопросом, что есть жесткая ссылка.

Comment: Понятно ))))

Comment: Не уверен (исходя из упоминания *процессов* в вопросе), что ТС имел в виду только ссылки файловой системы.

Так-то оно верно, но ведь при открытии файла к текущему счетчику ссылок (не помню в какой структуре ядра (не inode)) прибавляется 1, а при его закрытии вычитается. Это позволяет открыть файл, удалить его (из оглавления, количество жестких ссылок уменьшится) и продолжить работать с содержимым. 

Когда суммарное число ссылок обнулится, система освободит память на диске.

Возможно имелись в виду именно эти ссылки, но как их посмотреть, тоже не знаю.